# bash: matching single and double quotes together by grep

Tags: shell, double-quotes, single-quotes

The target is to match single- or double-quotes words in the text.

```
'foo'
"bar"
'buz"
# text
```

In the bash script from the book named Classic Shell Scripting (script 1), escaping quotes is required. How to do that?

```
#! /bin/sh - 
grep \(["']\).*\1 text
# script 1
```

An alternative solution (script 2) is .

```
#! /bin/sh -
grep -e "'.*'" -e '".*"' text
# script 2
```

The exact solution (script 3) by @William Pursell is more compact.

```
#! /bin/sh - 
grep '\(["'"']\).*\1" text
# script 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably mis-interpreting the question, but it seems like you are asking how to deal with properly escaping the quotes.  Just do:

```
grep '\(["'"']\).*\1.*\1"
```